# Laravel "queue:prune-batches" is not defined

Tags: laravel, queue, batch-processing, jobs

Following the Laravel docs, it says [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#pruning-batches) that the batches table should be pruned daily by running the following.

```
$schedule->command('queue:prune-batches')->daily();
```

I've tried running this command on my server and I get the error:

> Command "queue:prune-batches" is not defined.

I searched Google but I couldn't find any matching results for this error or many results for "queue:prune-batches" for that matter.

Am I missing something?

[image: Screen-shot of Command "queue:prune-batches" is not defined.]

Comment: What's your exact Laravel version? This command seems to have been added in Laravel 8.21

Comment: That might be the ticket. I'm on 8.18.1. Would you mind telling me how you were able to figure that out? If you want, add this as an answer and I'll accept it after I update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That command was added in Laravel 8.21.

You can determine your exact version installed by doing one of the following:

1. Check `composer.lock` it should have the exact installed version in there
2. Run `composer show laravel/framework` the exact installed version should be in the first few lines of the output
3. Check `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php` for the `VERSION` constant
4. Run `dd(VERSION)` in any route to get the constant from (3) dumped

Since Laravel is using semver there's generally no harm running `composer update` to update to the latest minor version and get all documented features.

Figuring this out is a rather complex process of searching the github repository for that command and finding [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/3b87b6f972de4445bed7458c810671f2bbc861cb) commit that added it. It lists all the tags that the commit was merged with and those start from v8.21.0

Answer (score 0):

Have you executed first the following?

```
php artisan queue:batches-table

php artisan migrate
```

Comment: I did. I have the job_batches table.